# Is there a jQuery plugin that turns text into smiley faces and hearts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
Hello how are you :) I <3 you!
```

Is there a jQuery plugin that can turn emoticons into HTML entities?

```
Hello how are you ☺ I ♥ you!
```

Comment: string.replace(':)', '☺').replace('<3', '♥'); (okay, not complete, but does do those two...)

Comment: I am starting to feel like plugin requests are not actually programming questions. Anyone else?

Answer (score 5):

http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/

google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery replace function

Assume text is placed in a Div tag

```
<div class="TestDiv">
  Hello how are you :) I <3 you!
</div>
```

Try this,

```
$(function() {
    var text = $(".TestDiv").html();
    text = text.replace(':)', '&#9786;').replace('&lt;3', '&#9829;');
    $(".TestDiv").html(text);
});
```